# Cannot save customized blender interface theme .xml

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I have blender 2.83.1 installed via Steam, and i have 2.90 alpha downloaded from blender.org

I've saved and customized interface themes in the past, and i followed the steps listed everywhere which are

edit > preferences > themes
tweak the values to your liking
hit the + button
name your theme
and it **SHOULD** appear in:  /2.xx/scripts/presets/interface_theme

but my new theme isn't there

it only shows blender_dark.xml and blender_light.xml (which also doesn't make sense since many more preinstalled themes have been added)

i customized the looks of blender on my desktop to my liking and i want to be able to send that same theme to my laptop

any help would be appreciated, i can't seem to find an answer anywhere and this is very confusing since I've done this in the past with no issue but now it no longer works for me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

of course i found the solution right after posting a question...
it's in the configuration file or directory apparently

you have to go to:

C:/Users/Your User Name/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.xx/scripts/presets/interface_theme

and the .xml files for your created themes will be there